# Error 'Not supported for type RangeIndex' when calculating weekly grow rate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe MyDf like this

```
MyDate      MyData      
2020-06-02  4588.0
2020-06-03  4555.5
2020-06-04  4604.3
2020-06-05  4634.1
2020-06-06  4617.8  
2020-06-07  4598.9  
2020-06-08  4596.1  
2020-06-09  4607.0  
2020-06-10  4601.6  
2020-06-11  4547.4
```

I want to calculate the weekly rate of growth of MyData column this way:

```
    #'WeeklyRate'='MyData'/pastweek('MyData')
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week
    MyDf['WeeklyRate'] = ((MyDf['MyData'] / MyDf['MyData'].shift(1, freq=Week()).reindex(MyDf['MyDate'].index))
                                           .fillna(value=-1)
                                           .astype(float))
    #ToDo:not sure if .astype(float)
```

But I get the error "Not supported for type RangeIndex" when I run the last line.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you set "MyDate" as your index, it will be solved :)

```
MyDf = MyDf.set_index("MyDate")
MyDf['WeeklyRate'] = MyDf['MyData'] / MyDf['MyData'].shift(1, freq=Week())
MyDf['WeeklyRate'] = MyDf["WeeklyRate"].fillna(value=-1)
```

Comment: I had MyDf.set_index("MyDate") instead of MyDf = MyDf.set_index("MyDate")